# Utility of SingleSignOutHttpSessionListener when a SingleSignOutFilter is used

Tags: java, spring-boot, logout, cas, spring-security-cas

I am currently trying to implement a CAS Client and everything is working fine. The authentication and the logout processes work like a charm. Here is my code for the Single Sign-Out process:

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean singleSignOutFilterRegister() {
    FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    SingleSignOutFilter filter = new SingleSignOutFilter();
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("casServerUrlPrefix", this.logoutUrl);
    registration.setInitParameters(map);
    registration.setFilter(filter);
    registration.setEnabled(true);
    registration.setOrder(1);
    return registration;
}

@EventListener
public SingleSignOutHttpSessionListener singleSignOutHttpSessionListener(HttpSessionEvent event) {
    return new SingleSignOutHttpSessionListener();
}
```

I did this because in every tutorial I've been through, they said to put a `SingleSignOutFilter` and a `SingleSignOutHttpSessionListener`. So it works, but looking deeper into each one of these classes, I don't understand the utility/purpose/value of the `SingleSignOutHttpSessionListener`. If I delete it, it still works fine, but I see in this [forum](http://jasig.275507.n4.nabble.com/Function-of-SingleSignOutHttpSessionListener-td263325.html) that sometimes, the session doesn't get destroyed by the filter.

**My question is: how could it happen, when could it happen, and how to reproduce it in order to test it**

Comment: When looking at the `SingleSignOutHttpSessionListener`'s javadoc ([here](https://github.com/apereo/java-cas-client/blob/81c7442dd309accbc19ffc8d2ebbb1e7e9a84f64/cas-client-core/src/main/java/org/apereo/cas/client/session/SingleSignOutHttpSessionListener.java)), I must agree that the purpose of this class is a little bit blurry. Mainly because it states that it "Enables the CAS Single Sign out feature", which is not quite true, because as correctly answered, it rather just takes care of a proper memory cleanup. So it _helps_ with the SSO feature, it doesn't _enable_ it.

Answer (score 1):

> how it can happened, when it can happened, and how to reproduce it to test it ?

The forum states:

> Sessions don't always get destroyed by the filter (i.e. they become invalid beforehand or someone doesn't log out of CAS).  The Listener handles that situation.

In a situation where the application session times out before the CAS SSO session timeout, (meaning the SLO filter does not yet get a chance to intercept SLO messages, because CAS has not had a chance to log out), the listener kicks in to remove the needed info from the session storage map. This could happen, as said because the application timeout happens before the CAS session timeout, bypass the CAS logout functionality that sends SLO messages for the SLO filter do its job.